# Can linux bond (aggregate) several GPRS (sticks)

Tags: linux, networking

is it possible to bond (aggregate) multiple connections over GPRS (usb stick) and use it as one link in linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is technically possible. Linux has a module called [bonding](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt) which can assemble several interfaces into one logical interface. If you set the mode of the bonding interface to `balance-rr`, it will distribute the packets between the two interfaces. You will also need a server somewhere to reassemble the traffic that will come from your two links.

However, in practice the results with such setups are awful, especially with high latency and high jitter links like `GPRS`. The main reason is that you get a lot of out of order delivery and protocols like `TCP` become crazy in these conditions. So the resulting throughput will never reach the total throughput of the two links.